# SQL query batch file to text too much spacing

Tags: batch-file, text-files, sqlcmd

I have created a `.bat` file that executes a SQL query and displays the results to a .txt file that notepad opens.

Everything executes fine but when the results are displayed in the .txt file, the rows have too much spacing in between them.

How can I get rid of the extra spacing?

This is the batch code I'm using:

```
sqlcmd -S SQLServer -i c:\scripts\Query3.sql -U user -P pass -o outputfile.txt
@notepad outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `-W` parameter to `sqlcmd.exe`.

> -W
>   This option removes trailing spaces from a column. Use this option together with the -s option when preparing data that is to be exported to another application. Cannot be used with the -y or -Y options.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Great! The -W command worked for me.  The only issue I have now is that it's actually too close.  How would I go about leaving like 3 or 4 spaces between them?

Comment: That's a bit harder. You could use `-s` to specify a separator character that you won't find in your output normally (maybe `¬` or something), and then (somehow) replace it with several spaces. String replacement in batch is possible but not fun. Unfortunately, you can only specify a *single* character to use as a column separator, so `-s "    "` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following commands inside your Query3.sql file

> rtrim(ltrim(field))

Where filed is the field you are pulling from SQL. The "rtrim" and "ltrim" functions remove white space which may be your issue.